# select with a multiple row in pivot table

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I really don't know how to retrieve a specific row from a pivot table.

Here's my pivot table:

```
+----+-------------+--------+
| id | peticion_id | tag_id |
+----+-------------+--------+
|  1 |           3 |     15 |
|  2 |           3 |     21 |
|  3 |           3 |     28 |
|  4 |           8 |     21 |
|  5 |           8 |     28 |
|  6 |          44 |     21 |
|  7 |          44 |     28 |
+----+-------------+--------+
```

I wanna make maybe i think is a dynamic query where for example if i do:

```
SELECT peticion_id where tag_id in (21,28,15);
```

The result is:

```
+-----+-------------+--------+
| id  | peticion_id | tag_id |
+-----+-------------+--------+
|   1 |           3 |     15 |
|   2 |           3 |     21 |
|   6 |          44 |     21 |
|   4 |           8 |     21 |
|   3 |           3 |     28 |
|   7 |          44 |     28 |
|   5 |           8 |     28 |
+-----+-------------+--------+
```

I need the result to be only peticion_id = **3**.

I don't know how to formulate the query, maybe I'm looking for the equivalent for(where in) to be an AND clause.

Hope somebody helps.
Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT peticion_id
FROM tbl
WHERE tag_id in (21,28,15)
GROUP BY peticion_id
HAVING count(*) = 3
```